# Why is the function displaying the hex code in reverse order?

Tags: c++, endianness

The following code (in C++) is supposed to get some data along with it's size (in terms of bytes) and return the string containing the hexadecimal code. `size` is the size of the memory block with its location stored in `val`.

```
std::string byteToHexString(const unsigned char* val, unsigned long long size)
{
    unsigned char temp;
    std::string vf;
    vf.resize(2 * size+1);
    for(unsigned long long i= 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        temp = val[i] / 16;
        vf[2*i] = (temp <= 9)? '0' + temp: 'A' + temp - 10; // i.e., (10 = 9  + 1)
        temp = val[i] % 16;

        vf[2*i+1] = (temp <= 9)? '0' + temp: 'A' + temp - 10; // i.e., (10 = 9  + 1)
   }

vf[2*size] = '\0';
return (vf);
}
```

So on executing the above function the following way:

```
int main()
{
     unsigned int a = 5555;
     std::cout << byteToHexString((unsigned char*)(&a), 4);
    return 0; 
}
```

The output we obtain is:

```
B3150000
```

Shouldn't the output rather be `000015B3`? So why is this displaying in reverse order? Is there something wrong with the code (I am using g++ compiler in Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing the order in which bytes are stored for representing integers on your architecture, which happens to be *little-endian*.  That means, the least-significant byte comes first.

If you want to display it in normal numeric form, you either need to detect the endianness of your architecture and switch the code accordingly, or just use a string stream:

```
unsigned int a = 5555;
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::setw( sizeof(a)*2 ) << std::hex << a;
std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Is this architecture platform specific or compiler specific? Sorry for this silly question...

Comment: It is architecture-specific.  Most general-purpose computers are little-endian these days.  Note that the compiler knows what architecture is being targeted, and so an endianness check can be done at compile time.